Trying to sum offset values in a Google Sheet
I am trying to sum all the score values (blue highlighted) for a particular team (yellow highlighted - "Cheltenham Knights").  The returned total should be 9.5 (4 + 3 + 2.5).
Is there a formula I can use to do this?
Please see this screenshot:

I have tried to combine SUMIFS() with OFFSET() but have got nowhere.

Click on the cell with the SUM formula then in the toolbar under format ribbon, click on the .00 -> to increase the decimal by one.


Based on the screenshot layout, the offset is hardcoded to 6 rows + 3 columns:
=sum(bycol(B:G,lambda(Σ,map(Σ,lambda(Λ,if(Λ="Cheltenham Knights",offset(Λ,6,3),))))))

Alternate:
=sum(arrayformula(if(B3:G27="Cheltenham Knights",E9:J33,)))


I should have said both of your answers worked. Thanks again.  I will try to understand how the first one works.  The first answer works was much slower to show the answer but I fixed this by deleting over 37000 empty rows in the sheet.

it has an open ended range B:G; you could simply limit it to say B1:G50 or so...

This question was closed by Stack Overflow with the message: "Closed. This question needs details or clarity. It is not currently accepting answers."  I have no idea why since the answer from @rockinfreakshow was spot on and very helpful. Clearly he/she  understood the question perfectly well.

My guess is your question is sharing just a screenshot to showcase your input data. the recommended method to share input data is by creating a markdown table using table generator to create the markdown_format & adding it to the question. screenshot OR sample test sheet can be additional supplementaries you can provide but they alone cannot be the primary source of the stack question here

Thanks @rockinfreakshow.   I have a couple of follow up questions which are driving me nuts but which I suspect you could answer in a flash.  If I try to ask a new question (this time in the correct format), would you be able to take a look?
